# Is it possible to set recipientId for docusign template recipients

Tags: docusignapi

I'm trying to set `recipientId` for recipients in template through `docusign API` using C# SDK.

When creating recipients for template i must use `TemplateRole` class which doesn't include `recipientId` property and it gets set automatically by `DocuSign` .

I'm not able to update it since it just creates duplicate recipient after creating envelope.

Is there any way around this?

Answer (score 0):

recipientId is a transitory field. It's used to refer to a recipient within an API request.

When working with a template, the roleName is used to distinguish between the different recipients.

What is your use case? (What is your problem that you're trying to solve.)

Note that you can **edit** / update your question.

Answer (score 0):

I am facing the same issue.
When we send an Envelope Document we have an option to set the recipientId.
But when we send an Envelope template we do not have the option to set the recipientId.

In order to describe in detail take a look at the apiexplorer to generate the problem I am talking about
https://apiexplorer.docusign.com/#/esign/restapi?categories=Envelopes&tags=Envelopes&operations=create

Choose the "EnvelopeRecipients" Also provide the "templateId". It will give the below error, which is understood.

{
    "errorCode": "INVALID_REQUEST_PARAMETER",
    "message": "The request contained at least one invalid parameter. 'recipients' may not be specifed when 'templateId' is set. Use 'templateRoles'."
}

Take a look at 
https://github.com/docusign/docusign-php-client/blob/master/test/UnitTests.php

```
function signatureRequestOnDocument
```

around line 81

```
$signer->setRecipientId("1");
```

You have the option to set the recipient

```
function testRequestSignatureFromTemplate
```

around line 152 - 155

```
$templateRole = new  DocuSign\eSign\Model\TemplateRole();
```

The TemplateRole doesn't have the option to set the recipientId.

The use case is when I am sending Envelope Template I want to set my custom value in the recipientId. So that when I retrieve the EnvelopeDetails later I can map the DocuSign recepientID to my Application's id.